# Does symmetric Lagrangian and boundary condition imply symmetric solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume I have a Lagrangian $L(x,y,y')$ such that $L(x,y,y')=L(-x,y,y')$. Moreover, assume that I am interested in the minimization of the action corresponding to $L$ under the boundary condition $y(a)=y(-a)=c$ for some $a,c$. Must a solution to the corresponding Euler Lagrange equation (under the given boundary conditions) satisfy $y(x)=y(-x)?$

If not, are there any additional requirements that can guarantee this?

I know that there are analogous theorems for initial value problems, but since we do not have existence and uniqueness here, I am not sure about the answer in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

If it helps, my particular Lagrangian is of the form:
$$L=y+a\cdot\delta(x)y$$

And I am trying to minimize:
$$\int_{-b}^{b}L(x,y,y')dx$$
Under the condition $y(-b)=y(b)=c$

Can anything be said about this particular case?

Comment: I don't know in this specific case. But it can happen that minimizers to symmetric problems are not symmetric. It is fashionable to refer to this as a "symmetry breaking". https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~dolbeaul/Preprints/Fichiers/proc-ICM2018-6.pdf

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks. I have added my specific Lagrangian. Do you think that something can be said about this particular case? Also, do they refer in this paper to symmetry breaking in the particular case of reflection symmetry of the function? I could not really find it.

Comment: I was just thinking out loud, I don't know if your problem will exhibit symmetry breaking. Just saying that this phenomenon exists

Comment: Can you write down the explicit minimization problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sure, I edited the post

Comment: Are you sure about that Lagrangian? Isn't there a square on $y$? The way you wrote, the infimum is $-\infty$ and there are no minimizers.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yeah I miswrote it, the second term should multiply $y$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Notation*. I will use $t$ as the independent variable, whereas you used $x$.

---

The answer is negative; there may be solutions $y=y(t)$ to the Euler-Lagrange equation that do not satisfy $y(-t)=y(t)$.

This happens even in the simplest example of the harmonic oscillator $\ddot{y}+y=0$, which is the Euler-Lagrange equation for
$$
L(y, \dot y)=\frac{(\dot y)^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}.$$
On the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, the most general solution to
$$
\begin{cases}
\ddot{y}+y=0, \\
y(-\pi)=y(\pi),
\end{cases}$$
is $y(t)=A\cos(t)+B\sin(t), $ which needs not satisfy $y(-t)=y(t)$.

---

However, this example is specific of the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. It is not generic. If $a$ is such that $\sin(a)\ne 0$, then the most general solution to
$$
\begin{cases} 
\ddot{y}+y=0, \\ 
y(-a)=y(a), 
\end{cases}
$$
is $y(t)=A\cos (t)$, which does satisfy $y(-t)=y(t)$.

---

I would be tempted to say that this is a general phenomenon; that "most of the times" the solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equations will have the same symmetries as the Lagrangian. But this is just informal chatting. I have no real facts to support this vague conjecture.

---

**The specific example**

The OP asks about the Lagrangian
$$L(y, t)=y +a\delta(t), $$
which I find weird, because the Euler-Lagrange equation in this case reduces to $0=0$ (see [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4176071/8157)). The action reduces to
$$
S(y)=\int_{-b}^b L(y(t), t)\, dt= \int_{-b}^b y(t)\, dt +a, $$
which is not bounded below, as we can take, say,
$$
y_n(t)=-n+\frac{c+n}{b^2}t^2,\qquad n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$$
which is a sequence of functions that satisfy the boundary condition $y_n(b)=y_n(-b)=c$ and is such that $S(y_n)\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if an [action functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) is invariant under a group $G$, then the corresponding [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are also invariant, but their solutions may not be, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451) related Phys.SE post. The latter phenomenon is known as [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking) (SSB), which happens in many physical systems.

Answer (score 0):

If Lagrange is T-symmetric (invariant under $x\to -x$), the Euler-Lagrange equation is of course T-symmetric, i.e.
\begin{equation}
0=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial(dy/dx)}-\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial y}=\frac{d}{d(-x)}\frac{\partial L(-x)}{\partial(dy/d(-x))}-\frac{\partial L(-x)}{\partial y}.
\end{equation}
Thus with the symmetric boundary condition, the solution must satisfies $y(-x)=y(x)$.
The same conclusion can be extended to T-odd $L$, i.e. $L(-x)=-L(x)$. Generally, if you have $L(-x)=(-1)^s L(x)$ with a symmetric boundary, you should have $y(-x)=y(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the solution is symmetric. It seems that you have only proven that if $y(x)$ is a solution then so is $y(-x)$, but I do not see why a given solution must be T-symmetric. Also, how does it fit with the comment by Giuseppe Negro?

Comment: @GSofer er, you are right.